# Creating a term frequency matrix from a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, sklearn-pandas, term-document-matrix

I am doing some natural language processing on some twitter data. So I managed to successfully load and clean up some tweets and placed it into a data frame below.

```
id                    text                                                                          
1104159474368024599 repmiketurner the only time that michael cohen told the truth is when he pled that he is guilty also when he said no collusion and i did not tell him to lie
1104155456019357703 rt msnbc president trump and first lady melania trump view memorial crosses for the 23 people killed in the alabama tornadoes t
```

The problem is that I am trying to construct a term frequency matrix where each row is a tweet and each column is the value that said word occurs in for a particular row. My only problem is that other post mentioning term frequency distribution text files. Here is the code I used to generate the data frame above

```
import nltk.classify
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
df_tweetText = df_tweet
#Makes a dataframe of just the text and ID to make it easier to tokenize
df_tweetText = pd.DataFrame(df_tweetText['text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '').str.lower())

#Removing Stop words
#nltk.download('stopwords')
stop = stopwords.words('english')
#df_tweetText['text'] = df_tweetText.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
#Remove the https linkes
df_tweetText['text'] = df_tweetText['text'].replace("[https]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}",'',regex=True, inplace=False)
#Tokenize the words
df_tweetText
```

At first I tried to use the function *word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(df_tweetText['text'])* but It would end up counting the value of the entire sentence instead of each word in the row.

Another thing I had tried was to tokenize each word using *df_tweetText['text'] = df_tweetText['text'].apply(word_tokenize)* then call *FeqDist* again but that gives me an error saying *unhashable type: 'list'*.

```
1104159474368024599 [repmiketurner, the, only, time, that, michael, cohen, told, the, truth, is, when, he, pled, that, he, is, guilty, also, when, he, said, no, collusion, and, i, did, not, tell, him, to, lie]
1104155456019357703 [rt, msnbc, president, trump, and, first, lady, melania, trump, view, memorial, crosses, for, the, 23, people, killed, in, the, alabama, tornadoes, t]
```

Is there some alternative way for trying to construct this term frequency matrix? Ideally, I want my data to look something like this

```
id                  |collusion | president |
------------------------------------------ 
1104159474368024599 |  1       |     0     |
1104155456019357703 |  0       |     2     |
```

EDIT 1: So I decided to take a look at the [textmining](https://www.christianpeccei.com/textmining/) library and recreated one of their examples. The only problem is that It creates the Term Document Matrix with one row of every single tweet.

```
import textmining
#Creates Term Matrix 
tweetDocumentmatrix = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
for column in df_tweetText:
    tweetDocumentmatrix.add_doc(df_tweetText['text'].to_string(index=False))
#    print(df_tweetText['text'].to_string(index=False))

for row in tweetDocumentmatrix.rows(cutoff=1):
    print(row)
```

EDIT2: So I tried SKlearn but that sortof worked but the problem is that I'm finding chinese/japanese characters in my columns which does should not exist. Also my columns are showing up as numbers for some reason

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = df_tweetText['text'].tolist()
vec = CountVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(corpus)
df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vec.get_feature_names())
print(df)

      00  007cigarjoe  08  10  100  1000  10000  100000  1000000  10000000  \
0      0            0   0   0    0     0      0       0        0         0   
1      0            0   0   0    0     0      0       0        0         0   
2      0            0   0   0    0     0      0       0        0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not optimal by iterating over each row, but works. Milage may vary based on how long tweets are and how many tweets are being processed.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tweets'] = [['test','xd'],['hehe','xd'],['sam','xd','xd']]

# result dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(row.tweets), orient='index').transpose())
```

Comment: I just gave this piece of code a shot. It is pretty slow since I have roughly 13,000~ tweets to deal with. I've tried other libraries like textmining. the problem is that it concats all my words and values to one row.